# Singleton Inheritance & Decorator pattern

Tags: c#, .net, memory, singleton, decorator

I have a set of static data, *MasterData*, currently being stored as a [Singleton](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton). Within a different library, I have a similar set of data being stored, again as a Singleton, *GlobalData*. GlobalData contains all the data from MasterData, as well as some extra information (see below for a simplified example).

```
public class MasterData
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<double>> DataSeries { get; private set; }
    public List<DateTime> Dates { get; private set; }
    
    public static MasterData Instance { get; } = new MasterData();

    static MasterData() {}
    private MasterData() {}

    public void LoadData() {}
}

public class GlobalData
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<double>> DataSeries { get; private set; }
    public List<DateTime> Dates { get; private set; }
    // extra data props
    public Dictionary<string, DomainObject> OtherData { get; private set; }
    ...
    
    public static GlobalData Instance { get; } = new GlobalData();

    static GlobalData() {}
    private GlobalData() {}

    public void LoadData() {}
}
```

My goal is to avoid storing the overlapping data twice in cases where both libraries are imported. In order to do this, I would like to utilize inheritance so that I can avoid duplicating as much of the 'LoadData' logic as possible - as well as let the applications using the librar(y/ies) decide which is needed.

From what I've read, it seems like the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) could be of use as I could store a reference to MasterData within GlobalData. However, I believe that would fail in applications where only GlobalData is needed. I know having both Singletons implement an interface would work, but that would result in duplicating the logic for loading the MasterData props.

I guess I'm wondering if what I'm looking to do is possible; and if it is, any help on getting there would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Leaving aside implementation details. Does `GlobalData` contain *the same data* as `MasterData` plus other data, or does it just contain *the same data structure*?

Comment: I think if you inherit MasterData from GlobalData you are giving an option of which class to consume depending on whether you also need the extra stuff in GlobalData. This requires, of course, the client to be aware of how to choose.

Comment: On a different note, [here](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton) is the best way to implement a singleton yourself.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, `GlobalData` contains the same data as `MasterData`, plus other data.

Comment: @insane_developer This is simply a syntactically equivalent, but slightly shorter, version of the simplest option on that list that leverages language features that didn't exist when that article was written.  There's nothing wrong with this singleton implementation.

Comment: @insane_developer The article shared in your last comment is shared at the top of the question...

Comment: @laventnc There are many ways of doing this. If clients shouldn't worry about the details, I'd make `GlobalData` internally (`private`) use the singleton exposed by `MasterData`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I didn't realize that. The reason I posted it too is because lazy initialization is not being used.

Comment: @insane_developer But it is being used.  The article you linked *explains why this code is lazy*.